# Dynamic toggling Flink job name in Datadog metric

Tags: apache-flink, monitoring, metrics, datadog

I have several `Apache Flink` jobs that are monitored in `Datadog`.

Problem I'm trying to solve is that I would like to have a single dashboard, and toggle the `Flink` job names (and environment) so I don't have to build multiple dashboard with the exact same context, but just a different job identifier/name. For instance, this is the JSON for a sample `Memory Usage` widget that I have:

```json
{
    "viz": "timeseries",
    "requests": [
        {
            "style": {
                "palette": "dog_classic",
                "type": "solid",
                "width": "normal"
            },
            "type": "line",
            "formulas": [
                {
                    "alias": "Heap Used",
                    "formula": "query1"
                },
                {
                    "alias": "Heap Max",
                    "formula": "query2"
                },
                {
                    "alias": "Non-Heap Used",
                    "formula": "query3"
                },
                {
                    "alias": "Non-Heap Max",
                    "formula": "query4"
                },
                {
                    "alias": "heap % of max",
                    "formula": "query1 / query2 * 100"
                },
                {
                    "alias": "non-heap % of max",
                    "formula": "query3 / query4 * 100"
                }
            ],
            "queries": [
                {
                    "query": "avg:the_flink_job_name.jobmanager.Status.JVM.Memory.Heap.Used.value{env:$environment.value}",
                    "data_source": "metrics",
                    "name": "query1"
                },
                {
                    "query": "avg:the_flink_job_name.jobmanager.Status.JVM.Memory.Heap.Max.value{env:$environment.value}",
                    "data_source": "metrics",
                    "name": "query2"
                },
                {
                    "query": "avg:the_flink_job_name.jobmanager.Status.JVM.Memory.NonHeap.Used.value{env:$environment.value}",
                    "data_source": "metrics",
                    "name": "query3"
                },
                {
                    "query": "avg:the_flink_job_name.jobmanager.Status.JVM.Memory.NonHeap.Max.value{env:$environment.value}",
                    "data_source": "metrics",
                    "name": "query4"
                }
            ],
            "response_format": "timeseries"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to provide `the_flink_job_name` as a variable, in the same way `env` is provided.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

We solved this by setting a global tag per job in the Datadog reporter with the job name: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/metric_reporters/#datadog

```
metrics.reporter.dghttp.tags: flink_job:<job_name>
```

A bit manual, but should allow you to achieve what you are looking for. We had to do it like this since it seemed there was no other way to create reusable dashboards using template variables.

Comment: I see that `job_name` is automatically set. If I use it in `Datadog` I'm able to see the actual job name. Problem is I don't know how to change a given query, for instance: `avg:the_flink_job_name.jobmanager.Status.JVM.Memory.Heap.Used.value{env:$environment.value}` to make use of the `job_name` variable/tag instead of the hard-coded `the_flink_job_name`.

Comment: sorry, I should have mentioned that we didn't find a way to do these queries in Datadog so we had to do it the way I mentioned. I have edited the answer to include this.